# Unabled to upload load "file", permission denied

Tags: php, upload, elfinder

i use elfinder to upload file throught FTP driver, but i can not upload file to server, elfinder show messagers dialog "unabled to upload file, permission denied". I have take owership for the user use FTP but not affected:(, please help me

Comment: You don't have the right permissions, what is there to answer?

Comment: Check your uploading destination has write permission??

Comment: i can use filezilla to upload file with this user, but when i use elfinder, i can not upload to server with this user.Sorry because my english.

Answer (score 0):

$newname should be full path to a new file. But in your script it is a relative path that seems to point somewhere inside /tmp

Comment: my relative path not point to /tmp, i can upload use cpanel and filezilla but when i use elfinder nothing happend :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding extra configurations to elfinder root. For example:

```
$root = array(
  // -------------------------------
  'driver'   => 'FTP',
  'host'     => 'ftp_ip',
  'user'     => 'username',
  'pass'     => 'password',
  // -------------------------------
  'port'     => 21,
  'mode'     => 'passive',
  'alias'    => 'folder_alias,
  'owner'    => true,
  'tmbPath'  => '/tmp',
  'tmpPath'  => '/tmp',
  'dirMode'  => 0777,
  'fileMode' => 0777 
);
```